# uclibc support by GCC

Tags: gcc, uclibc

'man gcc' describes a number of machine-dependent options for different platforms and architectures, but I don't understand the purpose of '-muclibc' as it is defined under GNU/Linux options, but not a specific hardware.

Could someone provide more details on it?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is unclear in "Use uClibc C library"? `-m...` options are not necessarily for specific hardware. `m` stands for "machine", not for "hardware".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-muclibc` is not supported by most GCC toolchains (as in, it doesn't do anything useful) because the person/company/distro/whatever that build GCC does not configure or build a uClibc multilib to go with it.

In toolchains configurations that *are* intended for use with uClibc, the option makes some configuration changes that suit uClibc. Of course, if the compiler was built *solely* for use with uClibc then this option will be enabled by default. If the compiler was configured for use with both uClibc and glibc/newlib/whatever, then the `-muclibc` option usually does double duty to select the correct libraries for the linker.